# How to override complex type property with string value using DefaultContractResolver while json serialization

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, jsonserializer

I have a class with multiple properties where some of the properties are complex type, those it self having their own multiple properties, I am looking a way to get only one property to serialize from complex type.

For example I have these 3 class

```
class Organization
{
    public Int32 ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Geography Location {get; set;}
}

class Geography 
{
    public Int32 GeoID {get; set;}
    public string Country {get; set;}
    public string City {get; set;}
    public string State {get; set;}
}
```

here I want to serialize the Organization class object, that should take only 'Country' from property 'Location' along with other properties, the json string output I am expecting as below using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method from NewtonSoft library.

```
{
   "ID":1,
   "Name":"Sales",
   "Location":"India"
}
```

I don't want to do it using anonymous type as serializable object, because this implementation I need to keep common for every object those are being sterilizing with this property type.

I am experimenting using `DefaultContractResolver` as I already have implementation to exclude selected property from serialization, in same implementation I tried by overriding `CreateProperty` method but its failing in conversion, also I am unable to get the value to set with newly created property as shown below. This is a try only I have no idea whether this is the right method to use for required functionlity! please suggest.

```
protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
{
    var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
    JsonProperty newproperty = property;

    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Geography))
    {
        newproperty = new JsonProperty()
        {
            PropertyName = property.PropertyName,
            PropertyType = typeof(string)
            //How to get the value from parent property to set with newproperty? 
        };
    }
    return newproperty;
}
```

Comment: 1) Why do this with a contract resolver when a [custom JsonConverter for `Location` might be an easier option?  2) Do you need to **serialize** or **both serialize and deserialize**?

Comment: @dcb I only need to serialize the object, I have implemented some common functionlity to skip and change the property name while serialization usin contract resolver, so along with these trying to implement this requirement as well. My problem is, I can not pass custom anonymous object in implemented solution. You are referring cutom JsonConverter if that is not using anonymous type plese suggest some sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I build this solution for above functionality, things are working as per my expectation but not sure is this a right way to do it.

**Contract Resolver**

```
public class DynamicContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, HashSet<string>> _serializableProperties;

    public DynamicContractResolver()
    {
        _serializableProperties = new Dictionary<Type, HashSet<string>>();
    

    public void SerializableProperty(Type type, params string[] jsonPropertyNames)
    {
        if (!_serializableProperties.ContainsKey(type))
            _serializableProperties[type] = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (var prop in jsonPropertyNames)
            _serializableProperties[type].Add(prop);
    }


    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        if (_serializableProperties.Any())
        {
            if (_serializableProperties.Any(o => o.Key == type))
            {
                properties = properties.Where(p => IsSerializable(type, p.PropertyName)).ToList();
            }

        }

        return properties;
    }

    private bool IsSerializable(Type type, string jsonPropertyName)
    {
        if (!_serializableProperties.ContainsKey(type))
            return false;

        return _serializableProperties[type].Contains(jsonPropertyName);
    }

}
```

**Custom Converter**

```
public class GeographyJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly Type[] _types;

    public GeographyJsonConverter ()
    {
        _types = new Type[] { typeof(Geography) };
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value != null && typeof(Geography) == value.GetType())
        {
            Geography obj = (Geography)value;
            JToken t = JToken.FromObject(obj.Country);
            t.WriteTo(writer);
        }
        else
        {
            JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);
            t.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return _types.Any(t => t == objectType);
    }
}
```

**Uses of above custom settings**

```
   private void btnTestCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Organization org = new Organization 
        {
            Name = "Finance",
            ID= 1,                
            Location = new Geography(){ GeoID = 200, Country = "India", City = "Pune", State ="MH" }
        };

        var changedProps = "Name,Operation";

        var dynamicContractResolver = new DynamicContractResolver();
        dynamicContractResolver.SerializableProperty(typeof(Organization), changedProps.Split(',').ToArray());

        var selected = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = dynamicContractResolver,
            Converters = { new GeographyJsonConverter() }
        };

     
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(org, selected);

        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
```

Comment: Nice! It helped me to resolve a type conversion upon serialising an object. Thanks!